# How to merge the previous state with the new state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

How to merge the existing state with the new state in react native using redux?"

i tried these

```
const Initial_State = { images: [] };

export default (state = Initial_State, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

       case 'ImagesFetch':

            return  {...state,  images: action.payload};

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

these two are returning the new state but not showing the previous state

```
const Initial_State = { images: [] };

export default (state = Initial_State, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

       case 'ImagesFetch':

            return  {...state,  images: [...action.payload]};

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```
const Initial_State = { images: [] };

export default (state = Initial_State, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

       case 'ImagesFetch':

            return  [...state,  ...action.payload.images];

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and the one is throwing and error, none of the above worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const Initial_State = { images: [] };

export default (state = Initial_State, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ImagesFetch':

            return {
                images: [...state.images, action.payload]
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Or better to safe if in the future you add to state other properties:

```
const Initial_State = { images: [] };

export default (state = Initial_State, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'ImagesFetch':

            return {
                ...state,
                images: [...state.images, action.payload]
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```